# Stuck on Meteor example “todos” loading screen when running on an android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, cordova, meteor

## Issue(s)

The Meteor “todos” example is stuck on the loading screen forever when I try to run it on an android device. As can be seen in the screenshot below, the following error message is shown:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE http://10.0.2.15:3000/sockjs/info?cb=...
```

Also the app indicates it is having trouble connecting.
Is it possible this could be due a bug in the Cordova Meteor 1.0 release? Or am I missing some important configuration/setup step?
[image: Meteor todos example stuck on loading screen]

## Setup / Configuration

### System Setup

- Meteor 1.0
- Ubuntu 14.04 VM with VirtualBox 4.3.18
- Motorola Droid Turbo (Android 4.4.4) with Developer Mode and USB debugging enabled
- Chrome 38

### Run these commands in the Linux terminal

- meteor create --example todos
- cd todos
- ifconfig <------- gives inet addr:10.0.2.15
- meteor run android-device –p 10.0.2.15:3000

### Open Chrome DevTools

- Wait until the “todos” app launches on my android device (it does launch but it doesn’t move past the loading screen).
- Then open up Google Chrome and type “chrome://inspect” in the search bar.
- Click on the “Inspect” link under the “Todos” app listed under my Android device connected via USB.

[image: Chrome Inspect USB Devices]

Comment: I'm familiar with Basic MeteorJS, but not on mobile using Cordova or Phonegap. In Android,  you must allow the application access to the Internet through the Mainfest file. I'm not sure how it works here, maybe it's automatic, but you need to give permission in Android app Manifest in general. It may be the problem for your example app not getting through the loading screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exapnding on imslavko's answer...

The mobile device downloads the intial templates and whatnot over USB, but after that is tries to load the data from the server. In your case the, the mobile device is (or should be) connected to your LAN via Wifi, provided by your router. I'm also assuming your dev PC is connected to that router.

Now the server is running inside a VM which would make it problematic for the mobile device to see your server. The IP in the VM (in your case 10.0.2.15) is not directly accessible from the rest of the LAN which would only see the IP of your host computer (likely 192.168.x.x).

When you run the command meteor

`run android-device –p 10.0.2.15:3000`

you are telling your meter to start a webserver at that IP, but you are also telling the mobile device to look for the webserver at that IP (which it can't see as stated above).

So what do you do?
2 things...

1. You will need to port forward from the guest VM to your Host PC. To do this...

   1. Get your host PCs IP... in windows run cmd, then ipconfig.... save that
   2. On your guest VM get the IP with ifconfig (in your case 10.0.2.15)
   3. On your guest VM, go to the Virtual Box menu at the top then Devices->Network->Network Settings... in that window click the "Port Forwarding" button.
   4. In there add a rule... HostIP = your hosts IP from step 1, Host Port = 3000, Guest IP = IP from step 2, Guest Port = 3000.... hit OK
   5. Next you need to tell your mobile device to look for the server on a different IP than the one the server is actually running on. Now that you are forwarding the webserver IP to your host PC you want the device to look at your host PC's IP

so the new command would be....

`meteor run android-device –p 10.0.2.15:3000 --mobile-server 192.168.x.x:3000`

Comment: This ended up fixing the issue I was running into. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for expanding on my answer. sometimes I am too lazy to write a long answer but I still want to help

Answer (score 1):

Your app can not connect to the server (it might that the device and your computer are on different networks, or your home network has client isolation turned on).

The code in the app explicitly holds the load screen until it loads the initial data.