# Why might iron-router always ignore waitOn and stop running on cordova?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am at my wit's end! If you've seen a similar issue or know where in `iron-router` I should start debugging, please let me know.

Here is the sequence of events in the browser, on initial load of `/`:

```
global waitOn
global onAfterAction
index.rendered
loadingTemplate.rendered
global waitOn
global onBeforeAction
index onBeforeAction
index action
global onAfterAction
```

And I see the index template on the screen. Notes: index.rendered is only called once, well before its action hook is called. When index.rendered is called, the `waitOn` subscription is not ready.

========================

**EDIT: the remainder was solved by fixing the DDP connection so that the subscription completed.**

That's all weird, but I can deal with it – eventually the pages loads. What's broken is Cordova. Sequence on ios device:

```
global waitOn
global onAfterAction
index.rendered
loadingTemplate.rendered
```

And then it stops, and I see the `layoutTemplate` on the screen but nothing where the main template should be. Subsequently calling `Router.go 'signin'`:

```
global waitOn
global onAfterAction
loadingTemplate.rendered
```

and I see the loading template (for the first time).

The browser behavior is old. The Cordova behavior is new. I've tried `meteor reset`ing, going back to an old commit I know worked, and going back to an old version of `meteor`.

Comment: This is definitely not the solution but maybe a starting point for debugging [SO article1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897287/how-to-debug-a-meteor-cordova-app-using-iron-router-stuck-at-loading-screen) and [SO article2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918902/stuck-on-meteor-example-todos-loading-screen-when-running-on-an-android-device). Would be helpful to see the Router config / maps or even better the full code on a public repo

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. The subscription was not ready, and I found that DDP wasn't connecting. Don't know why there wasn't an error logged saying DDP couldn't connect.

Comment: Glad to see that it directed you to the solution.